# Remove dirs from parent dir without deleting parent directory (Linux)

Tags: linux, unix, find, rm

I am using the following command to remove all dirs older than 1 minute from the following path:

`find /myhome/me/xyz/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/my_stats/ -mmin +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;`

folder structure :
`/home/myhome/me/xyz/<2 digit name>/<4 digit name>/my_stats/`

There could be multiple dirs or a single dir inside my_stats. The issue is when there is a single folder inside my_stats, the find command is deleting the my_stats dir as well.

Is there a way to solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you are probably looking for this:

```
find /myhome/me/xyz/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/my_stats/ -mmin +1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

The `-mindepth 1` parameter is what excludes the my_stats directory from the listing, as it is located at depth 0.

The `-maxdepth 1` parameter will not show subdirs of subdirs (you are deleting their parents recursively anyway).

The `-type d` parameter limits the output to directories only, not ordinary files.

Comment: everytime this command is run, it deletes the dirs that I wanted to delete but it returns a returncode 1. Can someone explain why? or how to handle this?

Comment: You can try to add the debug option `-D exec` as the first argument of the `find` command (in front of the path). Then search for the process which returned a non-zero exit status and continue analysis from there.